# Understanding the Purpose of overly simple Modules in jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read and understand jquery source at their [github repo](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) for learning.

There I saw some overly simple codes are put into separate modules. Say, for example, **arr.js** at [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/var)

Which contains only the below code,

```
define( function() {
    "use strict";

    return [];
} );
```

There must be some usefullness to it as it is in jquery source.

Now, can anyone please explain what is the point of defining a module which only returns an empty array?

I mean the concept of module is to break down big complex codes into smaller reusable chunks and things like that.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit. Some Clarification**

For Down voters and those who think this question is

> opinion-based question and therefore not good for SO

I am trying to learn from a very popular open source library. And there I saw something which I did not clearly understand. *It might be a best practice, or might be an overall great way of coding*. So I asked this question to get more insight/understanding into the code. It is a technical question so I asked at SO, [where would I ask if not here?].

**I DID NOT ASK FOR ANYONE'S OPINION**

If you feel the question is wrongly asked, SO gave everyone the power to edit it, please use it.

Comment: This is probably and opinion-based question and therefore not good for SO.  I would say that my guess is that they simply wanted to abstract out this module for returning and array, such that if in the future additional logic would be needed in this array, that the module is already decoupled from the rest of the code making changes easier to implement in that only the contract with the caller needs to be fulfilled (i.e. it still must return an empty array no matter what other logic is added).

Comment: How can "wanting to understand something" be a bad thing? I just wanted an explanation not anyone's opinion. We should study and learn from open source libraries, like jQuery. And where will we ask questions if we face problem while learning? I mean, this way, every question can be rejected as  "opinion-based question and therefore not good for SO". Sorry, but shocked... @MikeBrant

Comment: There is nothing wrong with trying to understand things.  But unless someone responding to this question is part of the jQuery development team, the answer you will get will by definition be opinion as to why someone might take this approach.  I gave my opinion in my comment above, but it is just that - an opinion. I don't ultimately know why they choose to abstract out this particular functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the history of **arr.js**, you'll see that the original commit describes it as:

> AMD-ify jQuery

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6318ae6ab90d4b450dfadf32ab95fe52ed6331cb

AMD stands for Asynchronous Module Definition. The purpose of AMD is to provide modularity in the jQuery code. Here's a good article that describes the purpose:

> When we say an application is modular, we generally mean it's composed
>   of a set of highly decoupled, distinct pieces of functionality stored
>   in modules. As you probably know, loose coupling facilitates easier
>   maintainability of apps by removing dependencies where possible. When
>   this is implemented efficiently, its quite easy to see how changes to
>   one part of a system may affect another.

https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

Answer (score 0):

I guess to enforce the "use strict".

e.g.

For this module

```
define( function() {
    "use strict";

    return window.document;
} );
```

in non-strict mode you can do `window.document = 10`

In strict mode is an error

**Cannot assign to read only property 'document' of object '#'**

Or it could be just there way of creating small modules that will be easier to refactor later.